# Maptile - Download png with coordinates

Tags: google-maps, overlay, geopositioning

**The goal**

I have to add a PNG overlay over an open street map. The PNG is a drawn road and I need to possisionate it over the real road.

**What I have now**

I have my PNG draw and 2 coordinates to place it over my map. The bottom left corner and top right corner.

**What I found**

I already found the software [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/) which can display an image and the map side by side or one over the other and place some point to possisionate it.

The problem is that it generates a folder that contains different splitted image and data. Is there a way with MapTiler to generate the png with the coordinate ?

Is there any other software that can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear on why you'd use MapTiler. Less is more. Keep it simple, make it easy. I did the same thing, but instead I played around with transparency to ensure I was able to align things up. Obviously, I'd do the line up by adjusting the lat/lon numbers in the code. It's very precise and easy to do.

final output:[image: Bootleg Canyon Mountain Biking Trails]

and here are some code snippets:

```
// Overlay a map of Bootleg Canyon
// Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.
var BootlegCanyonimageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(35.9691, -114.8824), // lower left
     new google.maps.LatLng(36.01217, -114.8468)); // upper right

var BootlegCanyonMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    "images/bcmap.png",
    BootlegCanyonimageBounds);
BootlegCanyonMap.setMap(map);
BootlegCanyonMap.setOpacity(0.75);
```

Comment: For the moment, I already have a code that can do this.. I exactly have an image over a map and I specify the lower left and upper right coordinate. I am just looking for a tool to do it manually. A tool where I can move with my mouse the corners and rotate the image if needed

Comment: Hmmm.. I exactly answered your question to meet your goal exactly as written above.  Boy, I wish you would have been clearer before I spent time trying to help. But, I do understand English may not be your first language.  At this point, you are going to want to review this [posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435288/positioning-image-on-google-maps-with-rotate-scale-translate/29809750), and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/3tzzwmsx/4/) I think that these will get you closer to where you now say you want to go.